# Simulink - Find computed index of multidimensional signal at specific time

Tags: matlab, simulink

I am trying to find which element(index) of a multidimensional signal is computed at a specific time in a Simulink model. Assume that there is a multidimensional input signal given to an add block together with a constant so Simulink calculates the sum with the constant for each element of the signal and gives the output as multidimensional signal. I want to know which index of the signal is computed at a time so I can do additional computation. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you want to do additional computation during simulation or after? In the latter case, you can save the multidimensional signal to the MATLAB Workspace as a "structure with time" variable. Then do your additional computations by finding the index of the time point of interest and the associated multidimensional data point. In the former case, you can probably a MATLAB function block with two inputs: the output of a clock block and the multidimensional signal. Then do your processing in there using MATLAB code.